# Pass Azure Devops pipeline variable to template without it getting set to the literal value

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, terraform, pipeline

I have a pipeline with a template that plans terraform using TerraformTestV1@0

I'm currently setting a variable depending on the branch and want that to set the variable group it uses but it's setting the literal value and trying to find a variable group with that value. E.G It's searching for $(variable group) instead of transforming.

I've tried using $[variables.countryCode] and $(countryCode) but get the same outcome. I'm also using another variable in the same way but this one is getting transformed.

I know the countryCode variable is also getting set because I have a powershell task beforehand I tested that shows the output I was expecting.

Here's the pipeline I currently have setup

deploy.yml

```
name: $(BuildDefinitionName)_1.0$(Rev:.r)

trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - 'refs/tags/uk-*'
    - 'refs/tags/us-*'
    - 'refs/tags/es-*'

pool: Default

variables:
- name: countryCode
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/es-') }}:
    value: es
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/us-') }}:
    value: us
  ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/uk-') }}:
    value: uk
- name: statefilename
  value: pipelinetest 

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: MyTemplateRepo

stages :
  - stage:
    jobs:
      - job: test
        steps:
              - task: PowerShell@2
                displayName: Split_Tag
                continueOnError: false
                inputs:
                  targetType: inline
                  script: | 
                    Write-host $(countryCode)

  - stage: Plan_Dev
    jobs:
    - template: terraform-plan2.yml@templates
      parameters:
        servicePrincipal: Development $[variables.countryCode]
        stateFileName: "$(statefilename).tfstate"
        variableGroup: Terraform $[variables.countryCode] Development Environment
        terraformVersion: '0.14.6'
        condition: ""
```

template:

```
parameters:
- name: 'servicePrincipal'
  default: 'CI Subscription'
  type: string
- name: 'stateFileName'
  type: string
- name: 'variableGroup'
  type: string
- name: 'condition'
  type: string
- name: 'terraformVersion'
  type: string
  default: "0.14.6"

jobs:
  - job: TerraformPlan
    condition: ${{ parameters.condition }}
    variables:
      - group: ${{ parameters.variableGroup }}
    steps:
          - task: TerraformInstaller@0
            displayName: Terraform Install
            inputs:
                terraformVersion: ${{ parameters.terraformVersion }}
          - task: replacetokens@3
            inputs:
                targetFiles: '**/*.tfvars'
                encoding: 'auto'
                writeBOM: true
                actionOnMissing: 'warn'
                keepToken: false
                tokenPrefix: '#{'
                tokenSuffix: '}'
                useLegacyPattern: false
                enableTransforms: false
                enableTelemetry: true
          - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
            displayName: Terraform init
            inputs:
                provider: 'azurerm'
                command: 'init'
                commandOptions: '-upgrade'
                backendServiceArm: ${{ parameters.servicePrincipal }}
                backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: $(backendResourceGroup)
                backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: $(backendStorageAccount)
                backendAzureRmContainerName: $(backendContainer)
                backendAzureRmKey: "$(short_location).$(tenant).$(short_environment).${{ parameters.stateFileName }}"
          - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
            displayName: Terraform Validate
            inputs:
                provider: 'azurerm'
                command: 'validate'
                backendAzureRmKey: ${{ parameters.servicePrincipal }}
          - task: TerraformTaskV1@0
            displayName: Terraform Plan
            inputs:
                provider: 'azurerm'
                command: 'plan'
                commandOptions: '-var-file="devops.tfvars"'
                environmentServiceNameAzureRM: ${{ parameters.servicePrincipal }}
```

This is the error I'm getting:
*The pipeline is not valid. Job TerraformPlan: Variable group Terraform $(countryCode) Development Environment could not be found. The variable group does not exist or has not been authorized for use.*

Any ideas why this isn't getting transformed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax to reference variables.

`$[]` is for *runtime* variables, which means variables that are set absolutely last in the process, *after* the YAML template is compiled. Unless you are specifically dealing with runtime variables, the safe assumption is that that syntax is incorrect.

The syntax you're looking for is `${{ variables.countryCode }}`, or `${{ variables['countryCode'] }}`. Any one of those should work. Compile-time variable references can be a bit tricky... some of those work in some circumstances, but not in others.

I've found the most consistently reliable syntax is `${{ variable.whatever }}`.

Comment: Thanks! ${{ variables.countryCode }} fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

There are three syntaxes:

- **Macro syntax**: $(variableName)

  Macro-syntax is evaluated at runtime. So if you define the variable and then dynamically change it during the course of the pipeline, $(variableName) will always have the latest value.
- **Runtime expressions**: $[ expression ]

  Runtime expressions are tricky. They are evaluated once at runtime. An important note from the first [few paragraphs in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions):

  > Runtime expressions are intended as a way to compute the contents of variables and state

  In my interpretation and past experience, a runtime expression must be the *entire right side of the equation*. So a few examples:

  ```
  variables:
    myLiteral: 'hello'
    myVariable: $[ format('{0} world!', variables.myLiteral) ]

  steps:
  - powershell: write-host '$(myVariable)'
    condition: $[ contains( variables.myVariable, 'hello') ]
  ```

  Interesting observation, when used as a condition the *$[ ]* are not required:

  ```
  - powershell: write-host '$(myVariable)'
    condition: contains(variables.myVariable, 'hello')
  ```
- **Compile-time expressions**: ${{ expression }}

  Compile-time expressions are evaluated when the pipeline is compiling/expanding. Unlike runtime-expressions, there are fewer restrictions on where compile-time expressions can be used so they can appear in the middle of a literal. eg)

  ```
  parameters:
  - name: firstName
    type: string

  steps:
  - powershell: Write-Host 'Hello ${{ parameters.firstName }}'
  ```

  **Very important:** only very specific variables are available at compile-time! Refer to the [Predefined Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) article as it has a table that lists which variables can be used at compile time.

  Also from the [same article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions), emphasis is mine:

  > The difference between runtime and compile time expression syntaxes is primarily what context is available. In a compile-time expression (`${{ <expression> }}`), you have access to parameters and *statically defined variables*. In a runtime expression (`$[ <expression> ]`), you have access to more variables but no parameters.

  The emphasis on **statically defined variables** refers to variables that are in the context at compile-time. It might seem like your *countryCode* is 'static' because it's declared upfront in the pipeline, but the reality is the actual value of the variable isn't resolved until after compilation has occurred.

---

From the example you've provided, the reason it doesn't work is because you're trying to pass a runtime value to a template parameter that results in a compile-time expansion of the variable group. At compile-time, the value of $(countryCode) is *"$(countryCode)"* which is why the variable group isn't found.

You'd need to make the parameter you're passing a compile-time evaluation:

```
  - stage: Plan_Dev
    jobs:
    - template: terraform-plan2.yml@templates
      parameters:
        servicePrincipal: Development $[variables.countryCode]
        stateFileName: "$(statefilename).tfstate"
        terraformVersion: '0.14.6'
        condition: ""
        ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/es-') }}:
           variableGroup: Terraform es Development Environment
        ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/us-') }}:
           variableGroup: Terraform us Development Environment
        ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/uk-') }}:
           variableGroup: Terraform uk Development Environment
```

In a similar topic, I think you might also discover the same problem with your *servicePrincipal* because Service Connections and variable groups are considered [protected resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/about-resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) that are secured using the Approvals+Checks API which is evaluated before the pipeline runs.  You might want to move the principal and the variable group inside the template and pass the countryCode as a compiled value.

---

**Update:**

After a little bit more experimentation, I was able to get `${{ variables['whatever'] }}` and `${{ variables.whatever }}` to resolve at compile time in the pipeline.yml.

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation, used ${{ variables.countryCode }} and it worked :)

Comment: Did you get a similar issue with the ServicePrincipal?